# I'm learning javascript and react and I don't understand why the function returns Array(0)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I would like to make a monthly schedule and have dates dynamically when I change the me and the year and here, to have the dates of the current me I did this function and I don't understand why it returns me Array(0)

```
const [moisActuel, setMoisActuel] = useState(new Date())

const genererJoursDuMois = () => {
    const jours = []
    const debutDuMois = new Date(
      moisActuel.getFullYear(),
      moisActuel.getMonth(),
      1
    )
    const dernierJourDuMois = new Date(
      moisActuel.getFullYear(),
      moisActuel.getMonth() + 1,
      0
    ).getDate()

    for (
      let jour = new Date(debutDuMois);
      jour <= dernierJourDuMois;
      jour.setDate(jour.getDate() + 1)
    ) {
      jours.push(new Date(jour))
    }
    return jours
  }
```

const joursDuMois = genererJoursDuMois()

Comment: @MatthiasMertens Sure can. You could even make it `const`.

Comment: You just have a small typo: `dernierJourDuMois` should not be initialised with `.getDate()`

Comment: @MatthiasMertens A for loop is a generic looping structure. We often use it for indexing into an array but that's not all that it can do. You can also do things like `for (let x; x = y.get(); y.next()) { ...`

Comment: It returns `Array(0)` because the array you are returning is empty, be sure that your loop is filling well the array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue in your code is the comparison in the for loop's condition: `jour <= dernierJourDuMois`. Here `jour` is a Date object and `dernierJourDuMois` is an integer representing the last day of the month. You're comparing two different types, which is why it doesn't work as expected.

Instead, you should create a Date object representing the last day of the month, and compare jour with this Date object.

You can check out this code, I just changed a few lines:

```js
const genererJoursDuMois = () => {
    const jours = []
    const debutDuMois = new Date(
      moisActuel.getFullYear(),
      moisActuel.getMonth(),
      1
    )

    // Changed this line to store the date object of the last day of the month, not just the day
    const dernierJourDuMois = new Date(
      moisActuel.getFullYear(),
      moisActuel.getMonth() + 1,
      0
    )

    for (
      let jour = new Date(debutDuMois);
      // Updated this line to compare jour (Date object) with dernierJourDuMois (also Date object)
      jour <= dernierJourDuMois;
      jour.setDate(jour.getDate() + 1)
    ) {
      jours.push(new Date(jour))
    }
    return jours
}
const joursDuMois = genererJoursDuMois()
```

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT